# Is it possible to trace a virtual number back to its service provider?

Tags: phone, sms

If a virtual number is only used to send and recieve messages, is it possible for somebody who know the number to trace it back to its service provider and somehow seize the number? (perhaps buying the number with a big price)
Does that make accounts registered with virtual phone numbers unsafe for activism?

Comment: Define "activism" Who is your adversary? Law enforcement might "ask" the provider for help. No need to buy anything.

Comment: "seize"? why would someone "seize" it? That's an awfully specific act. Whether or not that is possible is up to the provider. "Unsafe for activism?" -- that needs to be defined, and I'm not sure that the question follows logically from the previous question. So, is it possible to trace the number to the service provider?Of course. The rest are strange questions that we can't answer.